# Apple- or Shellscript | get attr. "src" of an image by it's classname and download it

Tags: javascript, shell, web-scraping, applescript

**Struggling with this one:**

1. Loop trough the var All_URLs containing url's as string
2. get all src attributes from images with the Class "image_stack__image js-default-img"
3. download all images to a folder and use the URL from the source page as img name.

Thats all i have by now and could not find a working solution (except a Action in Automator) which works as intended.

```
    tell application "Finder"
        set myPath to container of (path to me) as text -- SET MAIN PATH
    end tell


    set AllUrls to {"https://teespring.com/shop/CLASSIC-DODGE-CHARGER-MOP?aid=marketplace&tsmac=marketplace&tsmic=search#pid=212&cid=5819&sid=front", "https://teespring.com/shop/greaser-mechanics-t-shirt?aid=marketplace&tsmac=marketplace&tsmic=campaign#pid=2&cid=2397&sid=front"}

    --set ImageSrc to (script to get the src attribute from the class "image_stack__image js-default-img"

    --set IMGname to the Page URL where the image is

    set dFolder to myPath & "thumbnails"

    set fName to IMGname & ".jpg" as string


    do shell script ("mkdir -p " & dFolder & "; curl -A/--user-agent " & AllUrls & " >> " & (dFolder & fName))
```

Every help is highly appreciated. Thanks

## UPDATE:

1. Managed to get the src/url from the image containing the class
   needed.
2. Managed to download it to the Folder needed.
3. **Need to set the saved image name to the source url where the image
   came from.**
4. **Need to do all this in a loop, since i will have different urls and
   not just one as in the example.**

--

```
set home_path to (((path to me as text) & "::") as alias) as string

tell application "Safari"
    open location "https://teespring.com/shop/CLASSIC-DODGE-CHARGER-MOP?aid=marketplace&tsmac=marketplace&tsmic=search#pid=212&cid=5819&sid=front"
    set campaign_thumbnail to do JavaScript "document.querySelector('.image_stack__image').src" in document 1
end tell


do shell script "curl -f " & quoted form of campaign_thumbnail & " -o " & quoted form of (POSIX path of home_path) & "thumbnails/test.jpg"
```

## UPDATE 2:

Following up to CJK's code:

1. "cd ~/thumbnails;" | Does save to the desktop Folder "thumbnails. I need the relative path to the
   scripts folder in case the user moves the folder. Did not find a
   curl solution for it but a "tell application finder" that does work
   (line1)
2. The downloaded files have the same ending after the last / (560.jpg)
   and i tried to use the "set My_Name to do shell script "uuidgen" and
   add it to the sh. But i'd rather need to name the files 1.jpg ,
   2.jpg and so on.

   ```
   tell application "Finder" -- get filepath to file container/folder
       set myPath to container of (path to me) as text -- SET MAIN PATH
   end tell

   set allURLs to {"https://teespring.com/shop/CLASSIC-DODGE-CHARGER-MOP?aid=marketplace&tsmac=marketplace&tsmic=search#pid=212&cid=5819&sid=front", "https://teespring.com/shop/dodge-mopar-m?aid=marketplace&tsmac=marketplace&tsmic=search#pid=2&cid=2397&sid=front"}

   set JS to "document.querySelector('.image_stack__image').src"
   set sh to {"cd ~/desktop/thumbnails;", "curl --remote-name-all ", {}} -- need to set the location to the home folder of the script and the filename to 1.jpg , 2.jpg ..

   set the text item delimiters to space

   tell application "Safari" to repeat with www in allURLs
   set D to (make new document with properties {URL:www})

   # Wait until webpage has loaded
   tell D to repeat until not (exists)
       delay 0.5
   end repeat

   set the last item of sh to do JavaScript JS in the front document

   close the front document

   do shell script (sh as text)
   ```

   end repeat

Comment: The URLs don't contain a class `mainImage`

Comment: @vadian this was just a example. The class on the provided URL's would be "image_stack__image js-default-img" Thanks

Comment: HTML parsing depends strongly on concrete data. In  AppleScript  you can do it with `text item delimiters`.

Comment: @vadian: updated the script and resolved the part to get the image src with .js - I am just not able to solve Nr.3 and Nr.4 in my list. Grüess uf St.Galle :)

Comment: The result of both the `tell application "Finder"` _block of _code_ and the `set home_path to ...` _line_ of _code_ produce `"Macintosh HD:Applications:Utilities:"` in Script Editor. Why are you targeting that location?  Anyway, SO is not a _code_ writing service and if you want help with _code_, you really need to provide working examples of what you want as the result. For example, in # 3, pick an actual file from one of the URLs and show which one and what you want it saved as! As to # 4, that is what the `repeat` _command_ is used for, e.g. looping through a _list_.

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks for your answers. The result of the "set home_path to" does return the path to the folder in which the script sits. But only after you have saved the script to a location. I need this to save downloaded files to the same location, no matter where users save the folder/script. I know SO is not a code writing service and if this would not be a charitable project which i help making for designers ripped of by a company selling their copyrighted stuff, i would simply pay someone to have it done. So i try to do it on my own and learn something ;)

Answer (score 1):

To get all the images URLs from elements with class `image_stack__image` (assuming the elements of this class are `<img>` elements, and to cater for multiple images that all share this class name) this line of JavaScript will return an array of `src` attribute values:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.image_stack__image'), e=>e.src)
```

AppleScript will automatically convert this into a list when you use the `do JavaScript` command in *Safari*.

To `cURL` all the URLs into the directory `"thumbnails"` in your home folder, and save each image under the same name as the remote file, `cd` into the directory first, then `cURL` using the `--remote-name-all` option:

```
cd ~/thumbnails; curl --remote-name-all %url1% %url2% ...
```

**Caveat:** Might not download images with unusual URLs, such as those that are generated dynamically through a CGI request, or images whose `src` attribute contains base64-encoded data.  In fact, the presence of these in the `curl` request might potentially disrupt the entire request.

To concatenate the list of URLs returned from the JavaScript method so that you can bung it straight into `cURL`, just coerce the AppleScript list into `text` using `space` as the delimiter:

```
    set JS to "Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.image_stack__image'), e=>e.src);"
    set sh to {"cd ~/thumbnails;", "curl --remote-name-all"}

    set the text item delimiters to space

    tell application "Safari" to tell ¬
        the front document to set ¬
        the end of sh to ¬
        do JavaScript JS

    do shell script (sh as text)
```

Then repeat the exact same process for each webpage URL, by enclosing the appropriate lines of code inside a `repeat` loop:

```
    set allURLs to {%your list of URLs%}
    set JS to "Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.image_stack__image'),e=>e.src);"
    set sh to {"cd ~/thumbnails;", "curl --remote-name-all", {}}

    set the text item delimiters to space

    tell application "Safari" to repeat with www in allURLs
        set D to (make new document with properties {URL:www})

        # Wait until webpage has loaded
        tell D to repeat until not (exists)
            delay 0.5
        end repeat

        set the last item of sh to do JavaScript JS in the front document

        close the front document

        do shell script (sh as text)
    end repeat
```

That's the barebones of it.  You'll need to attend to error-handling in situations where URLs are of an unusual format or if a webpage fails to load, etc., but you now have all the tools to complete the steps you requested.

Also, I recommend reading the manpage for `curl` (type `man curl` into *Terminal*), and read about the `--remote-name-all` option and discover lots of other options that you might find beneficial.

But I'll do my best to help with any minor road bumps you encounter or queries related to what I've written.

Comment: Hello @CJK : Thank you so much for your help. I have been playing around with your code for a while but could not yet make it work as intended. I have read trough the manpage but could not find the --remote-name-all description? Also Google did not bring up anything detailed. Anyway, i will add your code i edited to my OT and add the questions/issue up there. Thanks again, every help highly welcome.